# Ubuntu 14.04 desktop disppeared

Tags: 14.04, unity

Instead of the desktop UI, I get a blank "wallpapter" screen after the normal prompt for password. Cant power down except manually turn off computer power switch.  Using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  Thanks.

Comment: If you are using unity, try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [this similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)? Does it work for other users?

Assuming those don't help, the commonest cause of the GUI failing for one user after login, is permissions; I tend to use the rather 'shotgun' approach of going to a terminal (ie ctrl-alt-F1), and typing

```
sudo -i
cd /home
shopt -s dotglob
chmod -R tom:tom tom
shopt -u dotglob
exit
```

& try again from user login (ie ctrl-alt-F7).
This makes the computer change everything in your home directory to be owned by you, even hidden files.